# Create a Map with specific parent node value and all of its child node values of an XML

Tags: xml, groovy, collections, xml-parsing, xmlslurper

I have a sample LEDES XML file https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/cbdc79e7 and I am trying to create a Map with Invoice node's `inv_id` value as key and all of its child elements `file_item_nbr` values as below

```
['Invoice 31' : [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33] 
 'Invoice 32' : [50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73] 
]
```

can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get it with sudo code:

- Use `XmlSlurper` to parse xml
- Read all `invoice` elements
- Build the required map

Here is the script:

```
//Not putting entire xml here, just pass the xml as string to parseText method
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
//Get the invoices
def invoices = xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'invoice'}
//Build the desired result
println invoices.collectEntries {inv -> [(inv.inv_id): inv.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'file_item_nbr'}*.text()] }
```

You may quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/4FEC7W)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for the solution it works, am wondering if is it possible to achieve the same from a JAX-B Java object which is generated from the XML?

Comment: @RanPaul, I believe, it should be very much possible. But it may be entirely different.

Comment: created another question for Groovy solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717505/groovy-create-a-map-with-jax-b-objects-specific-attributes can you please try to answer it?